# DataLabel hidden on highcharts spiderweb when resizing the browser

Tags: highcharts

i get that issue when there is any resize of the browser (it could be by going full screen, but opening the element inspector etc ...), there is one datalabel that hides after the resize. here is the chart before resizing [enter image description here][1]
and here is the chart ater resizing [enter image description here][2]
and here is my js :

```
Highcharts.chart('my_chart', {
        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
        },
        legend: {
            itemStyle: {
                color: 'white'
            },
            itemHoverStyle: {
                color: '#F9DC24'
            },
            itemHiddenStyle: {
                color: '#444'
            }
        },
        colors: [
            '#2c85fa',
            '#fc3'
        ],
        title: {
            text: 'Résultats par thème',
            style: {
                color: 'white',
            }
        },
        pane: {
            size: '100%'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: <?php echo json_encode($results['sequenceLib']) ?>,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'white',
                    overflow:"none", 
                    crop:false
                }
            },
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            max:100,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
            style: {
                color:'white'
            },
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="font-weight: bold;color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b style="color: white">{point.y:,.0f}%</b></span><br/>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Score (%)',
            type: 'area',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($results['sequenceMoyenne']) ?>,
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },{
            name: <?php echo json_encode($results['libelleComp'])?>,
            type: 'line',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($results['sequenceMoyenneComp']) ?>,
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }],
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 600
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    },
                    pane: {
                        size: '100%'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    });
```

as you can see, i'm getting my data from backend (sf1.4)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvBCs.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA0TD.jpg

Comment: Please reproduce your code on some online editor with sample data where the issue will be clearly visible.

Comment: here is a fiddle, even if it does not show the problem https://jsfiddle.net/co7Lzbv1/

Comment: If the fiddle doesn't show the issue, could you share your website sample then? I would like to debug this issue somehow because it is not clear if it is an Highcharts bug or some of your options affect this label.

Comment: the problem is that i cannot share the website since it's an intranet. However, it looks like the resizings gives opacity 0 and visibility hidden to the last element of xaxis

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only guess what could have an impact on this label. Try to force the showing this label or set the opacity to 1 after each resize, something like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uvhnsra8/